# Update package depencies

Tags: ros, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I was reading this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/Tutorials/How%20to%20add%20a%20system%20dependency)  on how to add dependencies to a package, and was wondering why one would "only" need to upgrade the **package.xml** and not the **CMakeLists.txt**, where the dependencies initially given at the creation of the package can be read, in the **find_package()** section?

I thought *catkin_make* in the **~/catkin_ws** would update the **CMakeLists.txt** according to the **package.xml** content, but after trying it is doesn't react as I expected it would.

Thanks & sorry if I missed that info somewhere !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266183/update-package-depencies/) by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2017-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is some nuance here.

Yes, the `CMakeLists.txt` will need to be updated if you add system dependences to your `package.xml`, *but only if that dependency is actually used at build time* (and if it's actually C++ (or some other compiled language) we're targeting).

So if a dependency does not provide headers or libraries, or some other artefact or piece of build infrastructure (like preprocessors, code generators, etc), `CMakeList.txt` would probably not need to be updated.

Having said that: the example shown on the page you linked to would seem to be a case where `CMakeLists.txt` would need to be updated -- assuming obviously that the dependency (ie: headers, libraries) are used by any of the C++ sources that are being build.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-24**:
for example: to add depency of a package to **tf sensor_msgs std_msgs** to publish a jointState (like seen on this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher)), do I need to edit the CMakeLists.txt ? Build infrastructure is new to me ^^

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-24**:
Yes. Whenever you use something 'new' in your code -- and that 'something' is not something that is local to your own pkg, you'll need to add it to your manifest and update the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Note that this is not ROS specific. The same would be needed in a regular CMake project.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-24**:
See also: [catkin 0.7.6 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html).